# Error in main() for function call from a derived class C++

Tags: c++

```
//Newton-Raphson Method:

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class ClassNewton {
    public: 
    double NewtonRaphson(double x0, double epsilon, double f(double), double df(double));
    virtual double f(double) = 0; 
    virtual double df(double) = 0;  
};

double ClassNewton::NewtonRaphson(double x0, double epsilon, double f(double), double df(double)){
        double xold = x0;
        double diff;
        double xnew;
    do {
        xnew = xold - (f(xold)/df(xold));
        xold = xnew;
        } while (abs(diff) > epsilon); 
        return xnew;
}               

class derivedClass:public ClassNewton{
    public:
    double f(double x){ 
    double function = (x * x) + (2 * x) + 2;
    return function;
    }

    double df(double x){
    double derivative = (2 * x) + 2;
    return derivative;
    }
};

int main() {
    derivedClass n;
    double root;
    double x0 = 1.0;
    double epsilon = 0.00001;
    root = n.NewtonRaphson(x0, epsilon, f(root), df(root));
    cout << "The root of the function is  " << root << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I checked the code up to the main function using an empty main and it could get compiled with no errors. However, when I integrate the main, I get the following error:

```
NewtonRaphson.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
NewtonRaphson.cc:52:44: error: ‘f’ was not declared in this scope
NewtonRaphson.cc:52:54: error: ‘df’ was not declared in this scope
NewtonRaphson.cc:53:47: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token
```

I would appreciate some explanations, I suspect I am using the virtual functions in a wrong way.

Comment: You're trying to call `f` and `df` member functions without an object. Also, what's your reason for using classes, inheritance and/or virtual functions here?

Comment: `f` and `df` are not members of the global scope, but member-functions of `ClassNewton`. That's also what the compiler says.

Comment: Furthermore, the declarations of member functions don't declare what you think. `double f(double)` as a parameter actualy declares a function pointer (on the second glance, it seems that's what you want - but you can't pass member functions pointers as arguments to that).

Comment: Ramblings continue - you're using uninitialized variables everywhere. Please, throw this away, do some reading on C++ and start again.

Answer (score 3):

First of all in this statement

```
cout << "The root of the function is  ", root);
                                       ^^^^ ^^^
```

there is invalid expression.

As for other errors then you have to use an object name that to call non-static member functions of a class.

For example

```
n.f(root)
```

or

```
n.df(root)
```

Take into account that this declaration

```
double NewtonRaphson(double x0, double epsilon, double f(double), double df(double));
```

is invalid because you are going to use as arguments non-static member functions `f` and `df` while the corresponding parameters are declared as non-member functions.

There is no need to define these two parameters of the function because you could simply call these member functions within the body of NewtonRaphson.

Comment: **Take into account that this declaration ... is invalid.* Well, the declaration itself is OK.

Comment: @jrok They are invalid relative to the intention.

Comment: Who are we to judge the intent?